# How to apply Pauli Matrix to alternative basis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information

I am trying to apply the Pauli matrix $ X = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} $ to the state $|+⟩ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0⟩ +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |1⟩$

Can anyone help me with this calculation if possible?

Comment: Go research how to write a vector in matrix notation. Happy hunting!

Answer (score 1):

Simply multiply the matrix $X$ with the state $|+\rangle$. The result will be again state $|+\rangle$ because you negate $|0\rangle$ which is $|1\rangle$ and also $|1\rangle$ which is $|0\rangle$. Since amplitudes of both basis states are the same, the state $|+\rangle$ is unchanged by Pauli $X$ operator.

Direct calculation:
$$
X|+\rangle = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
=|+\rangle.
$$